# Get MAX minutes from query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query that gets all the records for today. With the query below I get the difference from the time a ticket was issued till the current time. This gets the total waiting time.

I want to get the `MAXWaitTime` from my query result.

```
SELECT 
   DATEDIFF(minute, Issued, GETDATE()) AS MaxWaitTime 
FROM
   tblData 
WHERE 
   (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Issued), 0) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

This works fine I get the minutes back but for several records. I only want the highest.

My result:

```
32
50
25
```

I want the result to be the highest only:

```
50
```

Comment: You may want to consider changing the query to use `where Issued >= Cast( GetDate() as Date )`.

Comment: Or `WHERE Issued >= CAST(GetDate() AS date) AND Issued < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GetDate() AS date))` if `Issued` can hold future dates. That way your query will be [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable "Sargable (Wikipedia)").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the max function to get the highest value. [Check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx)

```
SELECT Max(DATEDIFF(minute,Issued,GETDATE()))AS MaxWaitTime
from tblData 
WHERE 
(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Issued), 0) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Query :

```
SELECT max(DATEDIFF(minute,Issued,GETDATE())) AS MaxWaitTime 
from tblData 
WHERE (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Issued), 0) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```